# Change the variable name in a For Loop to reflect the value of the iterator?

Tags: c#, for-loop, streamreader

I am trying to load text into memory from different text files. They are all words, and they are all grouped by the length of the word in their respective text files (e.g. words3.txt, words4.txt...)

I am using `StreamReader` to work with the files, and because of the syntax I am fairly certain I can iterate which file it's working with if I do it inside of a `for` loop. I don't see why I should have 12 different `using` statements.

```
String[] words3 = new String[2000];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + "words" + (i+3) + ".txt"))
        {
            String strTemp = sr.ReadLine();
            words3 = strTemp.Split(' '); //My current logic fails here
        }
}
```

I wanted to iterate through my different words arrays (words3, words4... words15) but naturally I run into an issue with the name of the array that I'm storing these in. It remains unchanged and so I would simply be overwriting it 12 times. In `VB.NET` I could concatenate an iterator variable to the array name like so (or something closely resembling this):

```
words & (i+3) = strTemp.Split(' ');
```

This obviously won't work in C# the way I've described it. What is the best approach to solving this problem? Can I put the arrays into a larger array and iterate through them somehow? In the text files the words are not stored on individual lines, they are separated by a single space. To save time, when I go to see if a user's word is contained in my "dictionary", I only want to search for a match in the array that houses words with the appropriate number of letters.

Comment: Rather than a `StreamReader` you can just use: `File.ReadLines(filename).First()` to get the first line of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int,string[]> word_dict = new Dictionary<int,string[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + "words" + (i+3) + ".txt"))
            {
                String strTemp = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] words = strTemp.Split(' ');

                word_dict.Add(i + 3,words);
            }
    }
```

Then to get the words back:

```
string[] words3 = word_dict[3];
```

Comment: If I just wanted to check to see if a word existed, could I use something like `if (word_dict[word.length].Contains(word))` to return a true or false value? That way I could skip assigning the arrays to another separate array, correct?

Answer (score 5):

Why not create a `List` of arrays?

```
List<string[]> stringList = new List<string[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + "words" + (i+3) + ".txt"))
        {
            String strTemp = sr.ReadLine();
            stringList.Add(strTemp.Split(' '));
        }
}
```

Comment: Or, better yet, a list of list of string `List<List<string>> stringList = new List<List<string>>();`, unless he knows that the number of words in each file will be _exactly_ 2000.

Comment: If he just splits the string, it will return an array of the size he wants. No need to declare the array.

Comment: Is there a specific advantage to using a List over a Dictionary in this case? I'm thinking about searching through either later when they are called upon.

Comment: It depends. If you want to quickly grab a specific file's content, the dictionary might be better. If you want the text from `word3`, you can more easily lookup in the dictionary using `dictionary[3]` rather than searching through a list.

Comment: Thanks @DaveZych. Your answer is extremely similar, but I am going to 'Accept' Lloyd's as it is working well. Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, an array of arrays (a jagged array) will work:

```
string[][] words = new string[12][];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
   using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path + "words" + (i + 3) + ".txt"))
   {
      string strTemp = sr.ReadLine();
      words[i] = strTemp.Split(' ');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary of type `<int, string[]>`. The key would be the word length, and the value would be the string array. Sorta like this:

```
var wordDict = new Dictionary<int, String[]>();

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + "words" + (i+3) + ".txt"))
        {
            String strTemp = sr.ReadLine();
            String[] words = new String[2000];
            words = strTemp.Split(' '); 
            wordDict[i] = words;
        }
}
```

By using a dictionary you can easily access the correct string array by using the word length (instead of having to know the index when using a jagged array or a list).

```
var words3 = wordDict[3];
var words4 = wordDict[4];
```